# parsing the output of an executable

Tags: python

I am trying to run an executable and parse its output,match the line with `QDLoader 9008` and then get the COM port value,output of the script should be`COM75` .
 My script below doesn't print the line with matched string,why is that?

```
import os
import re
import subprocess
'''
C:\Dropbox\h_loader>lsusb.exe
Communications Port (COM1)
Intel(R) Active Management Technology - SOL (COM3)
COMPANY HS-USB QDLoader 9008 (COM75)
COMPANY HS-USB Diagnostics 9025 (COM64)
COMPANY HS-USB NMEA 9025 (COM63)
COMPANY HS-USB Diagnostics 9091 (COM81)

'''

cmd = 'lsusb.exe'
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(' '), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

(output, error) = proc.communicate()
QD_line = re.search('QDLoader 9008',output)
print QD_line


EXPECTED OUTPUT:-
  COM75
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the output is something like `<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02B16988>`?

Comment: Rawing - thats correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re.search` returns a [match object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects), not a string. Even if it *did* return a string, it couldn't possibly return `COM75` - regex can't read your mind, how is it supposed to know what output you're expecting?

You need to change your pattern to capture the part of the output that you're interested in:

```
match= re.search(r'QDLoader 9008 \((\w*)\)',output)
```

and then access the captured string:

```
print match.group(1)
```